# Layout editor no longer works : Rendering Failed with a known bug

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Since the last update of android studio (2.3 Beta 1). I have an error for viewing layouts. The designs are just gray screens and nothing is showing. I have already tried several solutions proposed but none have worked. I already tried :

- Rebuild and re-sync project with gradle option
- Invalidate caches
- Change Android rendering version
- Checking updates and install latest version

`Rendering failed with a known bug. Please try a rebuild.`

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)



 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show 
 sample data when shown in the IDE.  If this is an unexpected error you can
 also try to build the project, then manually refresh the layout.  



`Exception Details java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: AppCompatTextHelper
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelper.java:58)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelperV17.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelperV17.java:40)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:72)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:62)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:441)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:240)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:195)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadClass(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:193)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:333)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:152)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:222)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:861)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:861)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:861)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:861)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:861)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:324)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:368)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:567)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:549)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:863)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:549)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$1(RenderTask.java:680)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Do you have any idea where this may come from?

**EDIT** : The bug has been reported to Google https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=1&q=230569&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&id=230569

Comment: I had the same issue on AS 2.3 Beta 2. Solved it by reverting to 2.2.3

Comment: @PiotrZawadzki the problem is solved on AS 2.3 RC 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After one update of Google it's working again

Answer (score 0):

**I think you have missing this dependency**

compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0"

just add it to build gradle

Comment: `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'`
(sry i can't edit my comment)

Comment: Please check is your sdk 25 is properly installed.

Comment: i have check, it's properly installed

Comment: change the apptheme to appcompact it will help

Comment: my apptheme is aldready in appcompact ... `style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"`

Comment: try to change theme to other.not appcompact

Comment: Like what, for example ? I only know this theme
EDIT: i have try with `Theme.Design.Light` and It does not work either

Comment: click app theme in xml try all the themes and change the  whole theme in style also.